# Problems importing rioxarray module in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-xarray

I am using Anaconda;Python = v.3.6.13;rioxarray = v. 0.4.0;rasterio = v. 1.10.  Everything is in a virtual environment.

The following is the code I am using to display a vector (aoi_shapefile) over a raster (example_mosaic):

```
import rioxarray as rxr
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.plot import show_hist
from rasterio.mask import mask
from shapely.geometry import box
import geopandas as gpd
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
import seaborn as sns
from shapely.geometry import mapping

# Open example mosaic & AOI extent shapefile
example_mosaic = rxr.open_rasterio(r'C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Land Suitability Model'
                                        r'\Layers\Sentinel\Sentinel RST\mosaic_b8.tif')
aoi_shapefile = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Land Suitability Model'
                                  r'\Layers\Sentinel\Sentinel RST\mask_proj.shp')

# Prettier plotting with seaborn
sns.set(font_scale=1.5)

# Overlay AOI & sentinel mosaics
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
example_mosaic.plot.imshow(ax=ax)
aoi_shapefile.plot(ax=ax,alpha=.8)
ax.set(title="Mosaic Layer with Shapefile Overlayed")
plt.show()
```

The error is produced when I try and import rioxarray:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-2-6111f71011c8> in <module>
> ----> 1 import rioxarray as rxr
>       2 from rasterio.plot import show
>       3 from rasterio.plot import show_hist
>       4 from rasterio.mask import mask
>       5 from shapely.geometry import box
> 
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Raster
> Analysis\lib\site-packages\rioxarray\__init__.py in <module>
>       6 import rioxarray.raster_array  # noqa
>       7 import rioxarray.raster_dataset  # noqa
> ----> 8 from rioxarray._io import open_rasterio  # noqa
>       9 from rioxarray._options import set_options  # noqa
>      10 from rioxarray._show_versions import show_versions  # noqa
> 
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Raster Analysis\lib\site-packages\rioxarray\_io.py in
> <module>
>      33 # TODO: should this be GDAL_LOCK instead?
>      34 RASTERIO_LOCK = SerializableLock()
> ---> 35 NO_LOCK = contextlib.nullcontext()
>      36 
>      37 
> 
> AttributeError: module 'contextlib' has no attribute 'nullcontext'
```

As a test I've tried importing rioxarray on a new line in my JupyterNotebook and the same error is produced.

Comment: Have you tried updating your Python interpreter? Contextlib is part of the standard libs.

Comment: I am actually not sure how to do this in conda.  Could this make things worse?

Comment: It's pretty easy: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#updating-or-upgrading-python
(And as general advice: do not get too attached to your conda environments. Keep a file with your packages (`environment.yml`), and if your env breaks, just delete and reinstall an environment. For much faster speed, also check out: https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba)

Comment: I now understand and worked through it by updating and starting over with new virtual env.  Thanks.  Beginning to understand that sometimes environments need some wholesale cleanup.